# Inject GET parameter to target URL of a button, on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fluid

I have multiple buttons with the class `myButton`. Each button has a value which is send to a server on click. The target URL of the button does look like this:

```
http://mysite/test/test.html?cid=15
```

After I click on the button, the following GET parameter should be added to the URL and then the button should be submitted:

```
mySessionVar=1
```

So the new URL should look like this:

```
http://mysite/test/test.html?cHash=d009eb3f9f4e1020435b96a8f7251ad5&mySessionVar=1
```

**Why I have to inject it?**

I am working with `fluid`. AFAIK it is not possible to manipulate fluid tags with JavaScript. However, I need to add a `sessionStorage` item value to the fluid tags `arguments` attribute.

My fluid code:

```
<f:link.action controller="Download" action="download" arguments="{cid: category.uid}" class="myButton">Download</f:link.action>
```

So my attempt is to append my sessionStorage item as GET parameter to the target URL of the button and then send it, e.g.:

```
$(".myButton").on
(
  "click",
  function(event)
  {
      //First prevent the default event
      event.preventDefault();

    ...inject the sessionStorage item as GET parameter to the target URL of the button, then do whatever the button would do normally...

      //Go to new URL
      window.location.replace(NEW URL);
  }
);
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: This is how the rendered HTML of the buttons looks like:

```
<a class="myButton" href="/de/mysite/test/test.html?tx_mydownloads_myfilelist%5Bcid%5D=15&amp;&amp;tx_mydownloads_myfilelist%5Baction%5D=download&amp;tx_mydownloads_myfilelist%5Bcontroller%5D=Download&amp;cHash=d009eb3f9f4e1020435b96a8f7150ad5">Download</a>
```

EDIT: I have another idea, maybe I could just read the target URL somehow, then add my new GET param to it and then load that URL with `window.location.replace`?

Comment: Can you please add how the rendered HTML of the button looks like?

Comment: why are you unbinding the click event?

Comment: @JohannesStadler i added how the rendered button looks like. WebKenth, I wanted to first prevent the default action and then allow it again, im not sure if it is done that way.

Comment: Hmm, i think i could just get the value of href, change it and then navigate to it :)

Comment: IMHO it's enough to add parameter to string before click. Kind of : 
`$(this).attr("href") = $(this).attr("href") + "sessionVar="+sessionVar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed just use the `href` from the button and use it to feed `window.location.href`, like so:

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href'),
        queryString = 'mySessionVar='+sessionStorage.getItem("myItem"),
        newHref;

    if (href.indexOf('?') !== -1) {

        newHref = href + '&' + queryString;

    } else {

        newHref = href + '?' + queryString;
    }

    window.location.href = newHref;
});
```

This also handles the case when there is no previous query string present on the link and appends it with `?` instead of `&`, but that part can be omitted if that won't happen in your app.

Comment: Actually I like this answer more than my one, @EdwardBlack you should use this one! :)

Comment: Thats similar to how I solved it :) but there is one problem, please replace `mySessionVar=1` with `'mySessionVar='+sessionStorage.getItem("myItem")`

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet should be enough to add your `mySessionVar=1` parameter to the `href` attribute:

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "&mySessionVar="+ sessionStorage.getItem('myVar');
});
```

You don't have to prevent the default, because your click handler function is called before the default event handler (who does roughly speaking: read the `href` attribute and load it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *.serialize* function in jquery which is simple and modern function to get all the selected buttons/filters into a url param format with amberson simple. I can't explain more clear than what is said in Jquery website. Please refer the link below  to find how to use the function. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/#serialize